# Retain Visible Attribute for GridView After Page Refresh (ASP.NET, C#)

Tags: c#, asp.net

- OK so I assume I need to use SessionData but I can't seem to figure it out.
- What I have is a GridView with a button that toggles its visibility
- Another button that adds data the GridView and refreshes the page to view it immediately.
- My problem is when the page refreshes, the GridView becomes invisible again until I click the button, how can I keep it how it was prior to refreshing.

GridView

```
    <asp:GridView ID="GridViewPrograms" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource" CssClass="Grid">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Firstname" HeaderText="Firstname" SortExpression="Firstname" ReadOnly="True" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="MiddleName" HeaderText="MiddleName" SortExpression="MiddleName" ReadOnly="True" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="LastName" HeaderText="LastName" SortExpression="LastName" ReadOnly="True" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ProgramID" HeaderText="ProgramID" InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="ProgramID" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Description" HeaderText="Description" SortExpression="Description" ReadOnly="True" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ProgramDate" HeaderText="ProgramDate" SortExpression="ProgramDate" ReadOnly="True" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView><br />
```

Button I have to toggle visibility of GridView

```
protected void ButtonPrograms_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    //Change Text Based on Button State
    if (ButtonPrograms.Text == "Programs") {
        ButtonPrograms.Text = "Hide";
    }
    else if (ButtonPrograms.Text == "Hide") {
        ButtonPrograms.Text = "Programs";
    }

    if (GridViewPrograms.Visible == true) {
        GridViewPrograms.Visible = false;
    }
    else if (GridViewPrograms.Visible == false) {
        GridViewPrograms.Visible = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your codebehind code like below

```
protected void ButtonPrograms_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    //Change Text Based on Button State
    if (ButtonPrograms.Text == "Programs") {
        ButtonPrograms.Text = "Hide";
        GridViewPrograms.Visible = true;
    }
    else if (ButtonPrograms.Text == "Hide") {
        ButtonPrograms.Text = "Programs";
        GridViewPrograms.Visible = false;
    }
}
```

Also in initial pageload you can set GridView visibility to true as below

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
          GridViewPrograms.Visible = true;
          ButtonPrograms.Text == "Programs"

        }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Combined Mudassir Hasan with while using a databind on the button that refreshes the page

```
protected void ButtonPrograms_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
//Change Text Based on Button State
if (ButtonPrograms.Text == "Programs") {
    ButtonPrograms.Text = "Hide";
    GridViewPrograms.Visible = true;
}
else if (ButtonPrograms.Text == "Hide") {
    ButtonPrograms.Text = "Programs";
    GridViewPrograms.Visible = false;
}
```

Databind

```
if (GridViewPrograms.Visible == true) {
        GridViewPrograms.Visible = true;
    }
    else if (GridViewPrograms.Visible == false) {
        GridViewPrograms.Visible = false;
    }
    GridViewPrograms.DataBind();
```